# Let $f: [- \pi, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$. Prove the following limit.

Tags: calculus, limits, fourier-analysis

I need help with the following question:

> Let $f: [- \pi, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable
> function such that $f(0)=0$. Show that
> $\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} f(t) \frac{\sin \left( \left(
>   N+\frac{1}{3}\right)t  \right)}{t} dt = 0$

Here's what I've tried: using L'Hôpital's, we can see that for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$,
$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} f(t) \frac{\sin \left( \left(
  N+\frac{1}{3}\right)t  \right)}{t} = 0
\cdot \left(
  N+\frac{1}{3} \right) = 0$. Then $\forall \varepsilon >0 ~ \exists \delta >0. ~ x \in (-\delta, \delta) \rightarrow f(x) \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$. Then I wanted to show that $\lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \int^{\pi}_{\delta} f(t) \frac{\sin \left( \left(
  N+\frac{1}{3}\right)t  \right)}{t} dt  \leq \frac{1}{\delta} \int^{\pi}_{\delta} f(t) \sin \left( \left(
  N+\frac{1}{3}\right)t  \right) dt \xrightarrow[]{N \to \infty} 0$, maybe using Riemann-Lebesgue. The problem is that $\delta$ is different for every $N$, and also I'm not sure Riemann-Lesbegue can be used like that. Any help would be appriciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a typo in all of your expressions? Do you mean $\left(N+\frac{1}{3}\right)t$ rather than $N+\frac{1}{3}t$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh shoot, you're right. Apologies, edited the post.

Comment: I think that you could apply Riemann-Lebesgue to $g(t) = \frac{f(t)}{t}$, noting that the conditions on $f$ imply that $g$ is continuous and well-defined.